# Solving a system of two equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations:
$$ \begin{cases} x\cdot y=6 \\ x^y+y^x=17 \end{cases} $$
I was able to guess that the pair $2,3$ satisfies the system, but my question is: how to solve such system of equations OR how to prove that this pair is the only solution?

Comment: I've done it. ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the tag is *Diophantine-equations* we can only have the pairs

> $$
> (1,6), (2,3), (3,2), (6,1), \tag 1
> $$

as

> $$
> x \cdot y = 6. \tag 2
> $$

Put it in and we get

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> (1,6) - (6,1) &:& x^y + y^x = 1 + 6 = 7\\\\
> (2,3) - (3,2) &:& x^y + y^x = 8 + 9 = 17
> \end{eqnarray} \tag 3
> $$

So the solutions

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { (2,3) - (3,2) } \tag 4
> $$

are the only ones.

Comment: from where do you know that this is a Diophantine equation?

Comment: It is tagged as Diophantine equation.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's not a Diophantine equations, but thanks anyway for your clever contribution.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: from the first equation we get $$y=\frac{6}{x}$$ plugging this in the second one we get $$x^{6/x}+\left(\frac{6}{x}\right)^x=17$$ this equation can be solved by a numeric method

Comment: this does not prove that the solution is unique

Comment: yes this is right this equation has two solutions, we must do more to prove this

Comment: But how to solve the second equation you wrote? Any hints?

Comment: use a numerical method e.g. the Newton method

Comment: and plot the graph of the equation to find start values for the Newton method

Comment: But is it possible to solve such equations using only basic methods like rearranging, substituting etc.?

Comment: i think no i don't know such a method in this case

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - you don't need any method, as the tag is Diophantine-equations and $x \cdot y$ means that the only solutions are $(1,6)$ and $(2,3)$.

Comment: i think the OP want to know all real solutions of the given system

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - the tag is then confusing. Anyhow I like your method - so +1!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for uniqueness. Suppose that we have a solution (a,b). Then by second equation (b,a) must be also a solution. Then by equation one we have
$$ab = ba = 6$$
Then (a,b) and (b,a) are symmetric. Which means if there is a solution, there must be at least one more solution which is symmetric to other. Namely if (2,3) is solution, then (3,2) is also solution. So solution is not unique.

Comment: this makes sense, but I guess OP meant are there other solution than $(2,3)$ up to symmetry of the solution

Comment: If this is the case, OP needs to clarify the question. Lets wait for him to speak.